# Como fazer o php retornar status?

Tags: php

seguinte.
Estou fazendo uma validação com angular e php, para quando um usuário for se cadastrar, seja verificado se tal usuário e senha já existam e não seja cadastrado novamente. E preciso que o php retorne alguma informação para angular para que possa ser exibida uma mensagem caso exista um usuário com os mesmos dados.

meu php:

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', true);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

include_once("conPDO.php");

$pdo = conectar();

$data = file_get_contents("php://input");
$data = json_decode($data);

$nome = $data->nome;
$email = $data->email;
$senha = $data->senha;
$idCep = $data->idCep;
$tipoUsuario = "C";

$verificaUsuario=$pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE nome=:nome AND email=:email");
$verificaUsuario->bindValue("nome", $nome); 
$verificaUsuario->bindValue("email", $email); 
$verificaUsuario->execute();

$quant = $verificaUsuario->rowCount();

if($quant != 1){

$insereUsuario=$pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO usuarios (idUsuario, idCep, tipoUsuario, nome, email, senha) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
$insereUsuario->bindValue(1, NULL); 
$insereUsuario->bindValue(2, $idCep); 
$insereUsuario->bindValue(3, $tipoUsuario); 
$insereUsuario->bindValue(4, $nome);
$insereUsuario->bindValue(5, $email);
$insereUsuario->bindValue(6, $senha);

$insereUsuario->execute();

}else{
   O que colocar aqui?
}

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Uma solução, é dar um retorno falso: `return false`:

```
else {
echo 'A conta já existe!'; 
return false;
}
```

E também troque `$quant != 1` por `$quant < 1`, se você não quer que inclua dois registros no **banco** você faz isso, `se $quant menor que (<) 1` retorna verdadeiro, se não retorna falso.

Veja se te ajuda...

Comment: Mas além disso, preciso que alguma informação volto pro angular para que eu exiba essa mensagem na tela, entende?

Comment: A entendi, desculpe, eu pensei que você queria retornar para o `PHP`, vou procurar saber aqui também ai faço update no meu post.

Comment: @GustavoSevero é interessante que você adicione esta informação também na pergunta, para evitar respostas equivocadas. Lendo rapidamente, eu imaginei uma solução semelhante a do Guilherme.